# Forcing AJAX call to be HTTPS from HTTPS Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, mixed-content

Currently making an AJAX call from a HTTPS jsp to call in data from another jsp page. We are however getting a Mixed content issue:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://etc/' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://etc/path/to/other/page.jsp'. This request has been blocked;
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

How do you force an AJAX call to call over HTTPS?

The AJAX call looks like the following:

```
var url = "/path/to/other/page.jsp";

$.ajax({                                                            
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {data: data},
    dataType: "html",
    timeout: 4000, 
    success: function(html) {
        /* Code on Success */
        }
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
         /* Code on Failure
    }   
});
```

I could understand if I was trying to make a call from HTTPS to HTTP, but I don't want to. I want to force this to call the JSP using HTTPS is all, so I can avoid the Mixed Content issue.

Thank you in advance!

/* EDIT */

Interestingly I put in the variable URL an absolute path:

```
var url = "https://etc/path/to/other/page.jsp";
```

And I got the same issue. Something is forcing this AJAX call to be HTTP?

Comment: The code as shown, when run from within a page that was requested via HTTPS already, should use HTTPS automatically, since that is how resolving relative paths to absolute ones works. If it _doesn’t_ in your case, then there must be something else going on that we have not been told about yet.

Comment: Odds are the problem is that the end point is redirecting off HTTPS. You have to fix that server side.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Quentin said: if you're explicitly connecting to an `https://` address and still getting an error about the the resource being `http://`, that means that the server is sending a 3XX (likely a 301 or 302) response to redirect to the `http://` resource. If you don't want this to happen, change your sever to that it doesn't respond with 3XX HTTPS-to-HTTP redirects anymore.

Comment: Where is that applied? Currently using apache?

Comment: Got it. We have that redirect but we also have a section which if the URL is submitted via HTTPS, then redirect using that. We have added in the URL to this section. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use another extension or use like folder with .htaccess etc. like this

```js
var url = "https://etc/path/to/other/page/";
```

Comment: How do I then call the specific JSP page that I need to get the data from the back end?

Comment: If apache installed in your server you can point files with apache configs