# Mixed content jQuery ajax HTTPS request has been blocked on Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, xmlhttprequest, cloudways

I think this question will be easy for someone and will be a face-palm situation for me.

I have a Laravel 5.3 site, and various pages have ajax requests. Because I use the [`csrf_field()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf) feature, they work fine.

But there is one page where the ajax produces this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/fb/reports' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/fb/json?levelType=&id=&aggLevel=ad&start=&end='. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
    var relUrl = '/fb/json/';
    var payload = {
        levelType: levelType,
        id: id,
        aggLevel: aggLevel,
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
    console.log(relUrl);
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: payload,
        url: relUrl,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }            
    });
```

I've read *tons* of articles about this error. I've tried tons of suggested solutions, including changing the relative URL to the full https URL, or starting it with 2 slashes.

I've even tried changing the way my Laravel routes work and am now using just querystring parameters.

I've studied all of the articles below (and more).

Also, since this one ajax query is in a password-protect part of the site (and the ajax queries that *work* are in a public/open part of the site), I figured maybe that was related to the problem. But then I used `SSH` to log into the production server and `vim` to temporarily remove the line that required any authentication, and the https error *still* happens.

What steps can I take to debug further from here?  What logs can I 'tail' on my Cloudways server?

Is there anything that Cloudflare might be interfering with (which I doubt, since other ajax queries work, all on https)?

Thanks!

- [jQuery AJAX Request to HTTPS getting served to HTTP with Laravel and Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008995/jquery-ajax-request-to-https-getting-served-to-http-with-laravel-and-select2)
- [This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134098/this-request-has-been-blocked-the-content-must-be-served-over-https?rq=1)
- [Mixed content issue - insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172075/mixed-content-issue-insecure-xmlhttprequest-endpoint)
- [XHR response blocked by Chrome, because of mixed content issue (http/https)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181846/xhr-response-blocked-by-chrome-because-of-mixed-content-issue-http-https?rq=1)
- [Forcing AJAX call to be HTTPS from HTTPS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277443/forcing-ajax-call-to-be-https-from-https-page)
- [MixedContent when I'm loading https page through ajax, but browser still thinks it's http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197528/mixedcontent-when-im-loading-https-page-through-ajax-but-browser-still-thinks)
- [jQuery ajax won't make HTTPS requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556772/jquery-ajax-wont-make-https-requests)
- [Laravel 5.1 ajax url parameter is url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153092/laravel-5-1-ajax-url-parameter-is-url)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Summary:**
I needed to replace `var relUrl = '/fb/json/';` with `var relUrl = '/fb/json';` (remove the trailing slash) because that's what my Laravel `web.php` routes file expected.

---

In Chrome console, I noticed that the `https` XHR request was being "canceled" and replaced with an `http` request.

So then I used `ssh` to log into the remote production server and `vim` to temporarily disable the requirement of authentication.

Then in the Chrome console, I defined and ran a new ajax command using an absolute https URL with querystring params on the end. That worked (no mixed content error). Then I tried a relative URL like that, and it worked too.

Even a relative URL with no payload or querystring params or trailing slash worked.

Then I added the trailing slash again, and it didn't work.

I still wish there had been an easier way to trace or debug the redirect paths or whatever was happening.  I still feel like I stumbled onto the answer clumsily (after many hours) instead of knowing how to dissect this problem reliably.

Comment: You ever solve this?  I'm dealing with it right now.

Comment: Yes. See my first line. Removing the trailing slash fixed it. That's why this is the accepted answer. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.  We ended up solving it.  It was removing the trailing slash, but Apache was also doing something to add a slash, so in our case, it was slightly more insane.

Comment: For me i had to enable Full ssl in cloudflare not flexible

Answer (score 0):

When changing from HTTP to HTTPS, it's possible to get the problem Mixed content issue - Content must be served as HTTPS.

So, first, modify `APP_URL` in the `.env` file, if we use the assets helper, this shouldn't give any problem with the URL.

```
APP_URL=https://url.net
```

Finally, add the following to the beginning of `**api.php**` or `**web.php**`:

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```